# Pulseaudio crashes when trying to combine multiple audio sinks (Steam Remote Play Together)

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, steam, crash

I try to play Ys: Monstrum Nox with a friend via Steam Remote Play Together. The actual remote controlling and video streaming part works fine but my pulseaudio services crashes so we end up without audio. We don't have this issue with any other game we play via remote play together. Here are the relevant syslog entries

```
pulseaudio[56699]: Assertion 'u->time_event == e' failed at ../src/modules/module-combine-sink.c:369, function time_callback(). Aborting.
systemd[1463]: pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
systemd[1463]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
systemd[1463]: pulseaudio.service: Consumed 1.783s CPU time.
steam.desktop[18793]: PulseAudio: Context connection failed
```

I can't find any information on this particular error message anywhere and tbh the error message itself leaves me totally stumped. How can I prevent pulseaudio from crashing?